# Bash forking a subshell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, fork

I have a bash script in which I want to run some unrelated commands in a forked processes.  These commands should only run in the forked process, while other commands should only run in the parent.

```
echo "I am parent statement 1"
( echo "I am child statement 1"; echo "I am child statement 2"; sleep 30) &
echo "I am parent statement 2"
```

In this example will the parent shell only output the 'parent' statements, and the child only echo the 'child statements'?  Or will the child echo parent statement 2 upon return?

As well, will the parent will wait for the child (doing a sleep 30)?  Or will the parent exit and the child keep running for 30 seconds?

Comment: Why don't you run it and see? You can easily add the pid into each echo to see which process is emitting it.

Comment: I tried - but it's not clear from the output which shell is outputting what.  and I'm not sure how to send some output to one window, some to another

Comment: `echo "$$: I am parent statement 2"` That will prepend with the pid which will help you easily identify where it comes from.

Comment: OK - will try that.  I also can't tell if the parent shell is still alive waiting for child shell to finish.  But control is returned (I see bash prompt).  Not sure how to interpret that

Comment: Put a print in the child after the sleep. You will see it gets printed quite a while after the parent exits (return to prompt). That should give you your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each process will only run its own statements.

If you modify your script slightly, you can do an experiment which shows that the child outlives the parent.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "I am parent statement 1"
( echo "I am child statement 1"; echo "I am child statement 2"; sleep 30) &
jobs -l
echo "I am parent statement 2"
echo $$
```

If you run the script and then do `ps aux | grep <pid>` for both the parent and child, you'll see that the parent has died while the child lives on.

Comment: This does not apply to the code you show, but note that `$$` in a subshell (a child process in bash) is *faked*.  You can see the effect with `(echo $$;ps)`, with or without the trailing `&`.